# How to know what is new in the daily releases?

Tags: versions

I see that https://builder.blender.org/download/ shows a new version almost every day.
But I can't see what was changed since the last version.
How can I know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Developers website](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/), or you can subscribe to [Bf-committers mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers).

Comment: More specifically this? https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/master/